# How to select drop down data (which has search functionality in it) in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can I select the dropdown data

Below is the HTML details

```
<div class="col-lg-9" xpath="1">
 <select class="form-control myLoginddl chosen-select" id="cmbLocation" name="sOfficeCode" onchange="LocationYearOnChange()" required="required" style="display: none;"><option value="0">--Select--</option>
<option value="999">999 - CESC Corporate Office(H)</option>
<option value="408">408 - NR Mohalla Division(D)</option>
<option value="473">473 - VV Mohalla Division(D)</option>
<option value="471">471 - Nanjanagud Division(D)</option>
<option value="410">410 - Hunsur Division(D)</option>
<option value="409">409 - Chamarajanagara Division(D)</option>
<option value="475">475 - Kollegala Division(D)</option>
<option value="411">411 - Madikeri Division(D)</option>
<option value="474">474 - Mandya Division(D)</option>
<option value="413">413 - Maddur Division(D)</option>
<option value="453">453 - Pandavapura Division(D)</option>
<option value="476">476 - Nagamangala Division(D)</option>
<option value="412">412 - Hassan Division(D)</option>
</select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 639px;" title="" id="cmbLocation_chosen"><a class="chosen-single"><span>--Select--</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div><ul class="chosen-results"></ul></div></div>
</div>
```

This is what i have used

```
WebElement LocationDropDown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/fieldset[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/span[1]"))
Select Test= new Select(LocationDropDown);

Test.selectByValue("473");
```

Comment: select tag has `style="display: none;"` thats why error you are seeing, enable that element then try, is that visible to you like normal web elements?

Comment: Hi Dev,  Yes its visible to me like other web elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='cmbLocation_chosen']//child::a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='chosen-results']//child::li[contains(text(),'473')]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
`WebElement LocationDropDown=driver.findElement(By.Id("cmbLocation"));
Select Test=new Select(LocationDropDown);
Test.selectByValue("473");`

Comment: Using above script i am getting this error:     org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Comment: Try adding wait before Select Test=new Select(LocationDropDown) statement.
Like
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(LocationDropDown);

Comment: now  i am getting this error:        org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (262551bd0afae14efbeab3b5d1b4b56a)] -> id: cmbLocation] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: I need more details then, please give more HTML details or URL and also your latest code

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will not be able to work with [Select](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class as underlying [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) is being hidden/styled using [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/)

So you will have to:

1. Locate and click this guy:

   ```
   <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 639px;" title="" id="cmbLocation_chosen">
   ```
2. Once done you will need to locate and click this guy:

   ```
   <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="8" style="">473 - VV Mohalla Division(D)</li>
   ```

First one is fairly simple, you can do this using normal [By.Id](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ById.html) locator

```
driver.findElement(By.id("cmbLocation_chosen")).click();
```

With regards to the second one you will have to go for i.e. [XPath starts-with() function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) to match on partial text like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[starts-with(text(),'473')]")).click();
```